# What should a new GM know when starting their first Paranoia game?

Tags: new-gm, gm-preparation, paranoia

I am a new relatively new GM (under a year's experience) and have only run/played Pathfinder. For this I have lots of resources: the beginner's box and its GM and player manuals, pawns, play-mat and pre-written adventures to ease into GMing. Paranoia is the second RPG I am trying, so I am comparing these helpful goodies to the brave new world that is a single book.

What should a GM coming from a PF/D&D fantasy background know to run a successful Paranoia game as it being their first time trying any other system?

Note for all citizens: references to official rules/materials will be reported to the computer.

Comment: Strongly related to http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7653/what-is-some-good-advice-for-starting-paranoia-with-a-new-group, currently discussing in chat.

Comment: IMHO, _Paranoia_ does a great job of explaining the "mindset" of the game, and how it differs from That Other Roleplaying Game(tm). _Paranoia XP_ even has a great section where it posits how D&D varients would look if they were played like Paranoia - does your book have that? Did you find those explanations clear and helpful?